# PG Promise not returning "timestamp with time zone" fields correctly

Tags: javascript, json, postgresql, pg-promise

I'm using [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) lib to work with Postgres DB. I don't understand why querying directly DB with

```
SELECT date FROM ro WHERE id = 13;
```

returns

```
date          
------------------------
 2017-01-19 00:00:00+02
(1 row)
```

and this pgp call:

```
var sql = 'SELECT date from ro WHERE id = 1366';
    Dbh.odb.any(sql)
      .then(ro => {
        console.log(ro);
        res.ok(ro)
      })
```

returns

```
{
    "date": "2017-01-18T22:00:00.000Z"
}
```

What I expect is

```
{
   "date": "2017-01-19T00:00:00.000Z"
}
```

Comment: The library might be converting to local time and the db is storing it in server's local time.

Comment: Make sure that you are using the latest version of the library, as the way time is converted was updated there not so long ago.

Comment: By the way, you are querying for different record id-s: `13` vs `1366`. Also, you are getting the same time, but for different timezones - `T00` vs `T22`.

Comment: If you query the db directly it returns `2017-01-19 00:00:00+02` with the `+02`  so `2017-01-18T22:00:00.000Z`  is correct. `2017-01-19T00:00:00.000Z` would not be correct, because it would be 2 hours off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you running `psql` on the same machine that you're running pg-promise?

From the docs on [`timestamp with timezone`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html)

> For timestamp with time zone, the internally stored value is always in UTC (Universal Coordinated Time, traditionally known as Greenwich Mean Time, GMT). An input value that has an explicit time zone specified is converted to UTC using the appropriate offset for that time zone. If no time zone is stated in the input string, then it is assumed to be in the time zone indicated by the **system's [TimeZone parameter](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-TIMEZONE)**, and is converted to UTC using the offset for the timezone zone.
>
> When a timestamp with time zone value is output, it is always converted from UTC to the current timezone zone, and displayed as local time in that zone. To see the time in another time zone, either change timezone or use the **AT TIME ZONE** construct (see Section 9.9.3).

So timezones are stored in UTC, and retrieved based on the `TimeZone` parameter, from that docs (slightly cleaned up)

> The `TimeZone` configuration parameter can be set,
>
> 1. in the file postgresql.conf
> 2. In any of the other standard ways described in [Chapter 19](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/config-setting.html).
> 3. The SQL command SET TIME ZONE sets the time zone for the session. This is an alternative spelling of SET TIMEZONE TO with a more SQL-spec-compatible syntax.
> 4. The PGTZ environment variable is used by libpq clients to send a SET TIME ZONE command to the server upon connection.

So you could always,

```
var sql = `SELECT date AT TIME ZONE '+02' from ro WHERE id = 1366`;
    Dbh.odb.any(sql)
      .then(ro => {
        console.log(ro);
        res.ok(ro)
      })
```

Or set the timezone for the client, session, or server.

You can find the potential values for `timezone` here

```
SELECT * FROM pg_timezone_names();
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `psql` output shows that the timestamp you have is at midnight but on UTC+2 timezone (2017-01-19 00:00:00+**02**) which is two hours ahead of UTC.

That is, when the time is 00:00:00 on UTC+2 it's only 22:00:00 the previous day on UTC - and that is what you get: 2017-01-**18T22**:00:00.000**Z**.

If you create a JavaScript date from that UTC date you will get midnight if you're on UTC+2. This is what I see in Chrome console on UTC+2:

```
new Date('2017-01-18T22:00:00.000Z');
Thu Jan 19 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (EET)
```

And if you really wish to have the timestamp stored as midnight UTC you should define the timezone when you insert the date. However do note that then it will not be midnight on UTC+2:

```
new Date('2017-01-19T00:00:00.000Z');
Thu Jan 19 2017 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (EET)
```